# SQL Server Data Tools 2017 with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, sql-server-data-tools, sql-server-2017

I have a .NET application using SQL Server 2005 which uses an SSIS package (.dtsx) to import data from .csv files.

That will be upgraded to SQL Server 2017.  I have installed SQL Server 2017, but did not install the SSIS capabilities, which I think are parts of the Business Intelligence group and should be available to install.

When I rerun the installation .exe (SQLServer2017-SSEI-Dev.exe) I do not see this as an option.

Does anyone have advice as to how I can install this module so that I can create a .dtsx package in SQL Server 2017?

My development environment is Visual Studio 2010.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked Sql Server Installation Center?

Comment: I don't believe you need the SSIS service for SSIS anymore, provided you're using SSISDB. The old SSIS service was for msbd deployment and file system deployment. If you were planning to use one of the old deployment methods, I suggest reconsidering., SSISDB is far better in my (and many others) opinion.

Comment: I've removed my answer since it was based on a false assumption, and edited your post to more accurately reflect your question.

Comment: @Brian i don't know why you deleted your answer, you were on the right track!! He cannot deploy ssis 2017 packages using Visual Studio 2010. You can check for more infor in the links provided in my answer.

Comment: @Hadi, I deleted mine because I didn't have the time to research the specifics of using VS 2010 to make SSIS packages for SQL 2017, and I didn't want to cause any confusion.  Thanks for carrying this over the finish line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments on @Brian answer *(deleted later)*, you are using Visual Studio 2010, and you are aiming to build SSIS 2017 packages, which cannot be done.

To build sql server 2017 integration services packages, you need to install SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2017 which can be found in the following link:

- [Download and install SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017)

You can refer to the following links for additional information:

- [Stackoverflow SSIS Tag Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ssis/info)
- [Installing Integration Services Versions Side by Side](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/install-windows/installing-integration-services-versions-side-by-side?view=sql-server-2017)
- [Previous releases of SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT and SSDT-BI)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/previous-releases-of-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt-and-ssdt-bi?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: OK, thanks very much Hadi. I'll try to digest this and let you know what happened. This is really confusing to me, unlike actually creating the package, which is simple in comparison. Thks

Comment: @user772047 each sql server version is related to some Visual Studio versions, there is a huge gap between Visual Studio 2010 and SQL Server 2017, since VS 2010 SQL Server Data Tools was not released yet, it was called Business Intelligence Development Studio.

Comment: Thanks Hadi, Thanks to your help, I think I am on the right track. SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2017 installed, and can now work on package.

Comment: OK, thanks.  This should be upvoted by 1 and marked as answer